# How to create an ArrayList of lines in Java processing?

Tags: java, arraylist, processing

I want to create an arraylist of processing lines in Java.  Not java lines.

My code for initializing arraylist:

```
 private ArrayList <Line2D> lines;
 // constructors
 public IrregularPolygon()
{ 
   myPolygon = new ArrayList<Point2D.Double>();
   lines = new ArrayList<Line2D>();
}
```

Code for making the lines and trying to put into arraylist:

```
 public void draw(PApplet marker)
{  

   if (myPolygon.size() >= 2)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < myPolygon.size() - 1; i++)
       {
           lines[0] = marker.line((float)myPolygon.get(i).getX(), (float)myPolygon.get(i).getY(), (float)myPolygon.get(i + 1).getX(), (float)myPolygon.get(i + 1).getY());
           marker.line((float)myPolygon.get(0).getX(), (float)myPolygon.get(0).getY(), (float)myPolygon.get(i + 1).getX(), (float)myPolygon.get(i + 1).getY());
           if (myPolygon.size() > 4 && i > 2)
           {
              myPolygon.remove(myPolygon.get(i));
           }
       }
   }

}
```

For some reason, I can't do lines[0] = .... it gives me this error: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList

What's wrong?

Comment: what does marker.line(...) return ?

Comment: It draws a line

Comment: You need to break up those super long lines of code into some variables. That's near unreadable.

Comment: those variables are just the parameters of the method

Answer (score 1):

If `lines` is an `ArrayList`, then you will want to call either `lines.add(...)` or `lines.set(0, ...)`, depending on the size of your array at the time.

Comment: I'm getting this:

Comment: The method set(int, Line2D) in the type ArrayList<Line2D> is not applicable for the arguments (int, void)

Comment: My guess is that the processing line doesn't actually return a line

Comment: How exactly are you using that line to cause that problem?

Comment: I'm trying to add the line it is making to the array, but it won't let me.  If i don't use the add method, it just draws a line on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

since you are using a list use add/set method to add line objects to the list and use get method to read the same from the list.

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason, I can't do lines[0] = .... it gives me this error: The type of the expression must be an array type but it
>   resolved to ArrayList
>
> What's wrong?

Replace

`lines[0] = marker.line((float)myPolygon.get(i).getX(), (float)myPolygon.get(i).getY(), (float)myPolygon.get(i + 1).getX(), (float)myPolygon.get(i + 1).getY());`

with

`lines.add(marker.line((float)myPolygon.get(i).getX(), (float)myPolygon.get(i).getY(), (float)myPolygon.get(i + 1).getX(), (float)myPolygon.get(i + 1).getY()));`

Comment: What is the return type of the 'line' method of your pApplet class?

Comment: @LarryJing You need to respond fast if you want to get a solution to your problem. You are not providing enough information for anyone to provide you with a solution.

Comment: I don't really know what the return type is, it's just the processing line.

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason, I can't do lines[0] = ....

Like other people have said, you're trying to use array access syntax on an `ArrayList` object. That won't work.

If you want to add an object to your `ArrayList`, then you need to use the `add()` function.

```
Line2D yourLine = //...
lines.add(yourLine);
```

Then to get an object, you'd use the `get()` function. Notice that you're already doing this with the `myPolygon` `ArrayList`.

Another thing to consider with this line:

```
myPolygon.remove(myPolygon.get(i));
```

Note that you're iterating over your `myPolygon` `ArrayList` from the beginning. So the indexes are 0, 1, 2... in that order. If you remove an object from `myPolygon`, then all of the subsequent objects are shifted down one index. So when your loop iterates, you go to the next index, but you've skipped over the object that was at that index before the removal. This can lead to unexpected behavior and other bugs. To fix this, you should either use an `Iterator` or loop over your `ArrayList` in reverse order.